# Adding keys in JSON array input

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have input JSON array of arrays and need to assign them with a set of keys.

```
{
 "dummyValues": [
    [
        0.57,
        0.52,
        0.51,
        0.50 // ... many more
    ],
    [
        0.56,
        0.52,
        0.50,
        0.49,
        0.46 // ... many more
    ],
 ]
}
```

These are the set of keys needed to assign them with in order.

```
const keys = [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    "D",
    "E" // ... many more
]
```

The result I want would look like this:

```
{
  "dummyValues": [
    {
        "A": 0.57,
        "B": 0.52,
        "C": 0.51,
        "D": 0.50 ..many more
    },
    {
        "A": 0.56,
        "B": 0.52,
        "C": 0.50,
        "D": 0.49,
        "E": 0.46 ..many more
    },
 ]
}
```

** I want to use JavaScript only **

Comment: The example output is malformed. I think you mean at array of objects, as opposed to an array of arrays (the array `[ "A": 0.57, "B": ...]` is not correct

Comment: USe Array.reduce to turn it into an object. You can use the index to get the key from the other array.

Comment: Please add the code _you've_ attempted to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: @ChrisG
Can you tell me how can reduce help me?

Comment: I figure the OP wants an array of objects, like `{ "A": 0.57 }`.  Incidentally, I notice no attempt at a solution, an odd, command-like phrase at the end of the question, and no response by the OP to multiple answers supplied to them on this site.

Comment: Having said all that, given two arrays keys and values of the same length, join them in with a loop so you get `[[key[0], value[0]], [key[1], value[1]], ...`, that's exactly the input needed by `Object.fromEntries()`

Comment: @danh Yes, that's what I figured, but had to alert them to the malformed JSON example they say they wanted. Anyways, I answered according to what I thought they wanted, which is to convert the arrays to objects with keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let newObj = {
 dummyValues: [],
};

const keys = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];

const obj = {
 dummyValues: [
  [0.57, 0.52, 0.51, 0.5],
  [0.56, 0.52, 0.5, 0.49, 0.46],
 ],
};

let numOfDummyArrays = obj.dummyValues.length;

for (let i = 0; i < numOfDummyArrays; i++) {
 let temp = {};

 for (let j in obj.dummyValues[i]) {
  temp[keys[j]] = obj.dummyValues[i][j];
 }

 newObj.dummyValues.push(temp);
}

console.log(newObj);

// result
// {
//  dummyValues: [
//    { A: 0.57, B: 0.52, C: 0.51, D: 0.5 },
//    { A: 0.56, B: 0.52, C: 0.5, D: 0.49, E: 0.46 }
//   ]
//  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary thing to know is that you can get any string, from any source, and simply assign the key to the object.

E.g. `anyObject["anyString"] = 123;`

Of course "anyString" can be a variable such as `anyObject[keyValues[0]] = 123;`

```
var input = {
 "dummyValues": [
    [
        0.57,
        0.52,
        0.51,
        0.50 // ..many more
    ],
    [
        0.56,
        0.52,
        0.50,
        0.49,
        0.46 // ..many more
    ],
 ]
};

// you need to make sure there is at least as much keys here as there are values above
var keyValues= [
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
    "D",
    "E", // and so on...
];

var output = { dummyValues: [] }

for(var di of input.dummyValues){
    var abcd = {};

    for(var i = 0; i<di.length; i++){
       abcd[keyValues[i]] = di[i];
    }
    
    output.dummyValues.push(abcd)    
}
```

`output` now is like you want it:

[image]

`console.log(JSON.stringify(output, null, '   '))`

```
{
   "dummyValues": [
      {
         "A": 0.57,
         "B": 0.52,
         "C": 0.51,
         "D": 0.5
      },
      {
         "A": 0.56,
         "B": 0.52,
         "C": 0.5,
         "D": 0.49,
         "E": 0.46
      }
   ]
}
```